# Azure Monitor Alerts - correlation to ApplicationInsight TraceId

Tags: azure, azure-monitoring

We're using Azure Alerts to notify us on failures of our resources. This question relates ApplicationInsight Exceptions originated from AZ functions. The alert we receive looks like this:

```json
{
  "schemaId": "azureMonitorCommonAlertSchema",
  "data": {
    "essentials": {
      "alertId": "/subscriptions/XXXX/providers/Microsoft.AlertsManagement/alerts/YYYYY",
      "alertRule": "DEMO - Web Exception",
      "severity": "Sev0",
      "signalType": "Metric",
      "monitorCondition": "Resolved",
      "monitoringService": "Platform",
      "alertTargetIDs": [
        "/subscriptions/XXXXX/resourcegroups/tabort/providers/microsoft.insights/components/exceptionwebapplication"
      ],
      "configurationItems": [
        "exceptionwebapplication"
      ],
      "originAlertId": "XXXXX_TaBort_microsoft.insights_metricAlerts_DEMO - Web Exception_2070165792",
      "firedDateTime": "2023-11-21T21:15:26.8290515Z",
      "resolvedDateTime": "2023-11-21T21:27:32.0055743Z",
      "description": "Please visit Azure portal for more information",
      "essentialsVersion": "1.0",
      "alertContextVersion": "1.0"
    },
    "alertContext": "{...}"
  }
}
```

Except for `firedDateTime`  there is nothing helping me to find the issue in ApplicationInsight. The `configurationItems` points to the Function App, of which we may have many functions. Is it possible to somehow include the AI TraceId?

Answer (score 1):

> Azure Monitor Alerts - correlation to ApplicationInsight TraceId

Using Alerts, the message of alerts is predefined we cannot customize it.
To customize alerts, you can alternatively use Azure Logic apps for that:

[image]

In condition you can keep yours when you want to send an email or sms as the alert using Azure Logic Apps. Here you can only send email with logs that come from that kql query not everything, this is a limitation too.