# Changing Azure alert payload (content)

Tags: azure-application-insights, azure-monitoring, azure-alerts

We are setting up Azure alert based on a certain key word in application insights.
For example, the log has 'Error occurred for ID: 111' and alert rule search 'Error occurred'. All good. But I would like to send ID: 111 as well in the alert message.
How to achieve this?

Couldn't find any configurations.

Comment: can you tell me how you are setting up the azure alerts? and can you please share if any code is used? share more information about your issue.

Comment: Just using Azure monitoring and alert management screen.

Answer (score 0):

> Changing Azure alert payload (content) How to achieve this?Couldn't find any configurations.

Using Alerts you cannot send custom payload or messages.
But Alternatively you can use Logic apps to send custom message with it like using below design:

[image]

Then use condition what is threshold and like that:

[image]

Here, you can send sms also and do all the things you do in alerts. Also refer [SO-Thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77526082/azure-monitor-alerts-correlation-to-applicationinsight-traceid/77589149#77589149).